# netbeans setFileSelectionMode not supported

Tags: java, swing

I have JFileChooser and I want to make it choose only directories but I don't know why setFileSelectionMode make an error for me and a lot of other classes I tried to use.

Hint: I updated my NetBeans version recently and I installed jdk-8u111-nb-8_2-windows-x64.exe

[image]

Comment: Something seems wrong with the class name in the error message : `JfileChooser` vs `JFileChooser` . Are you using a custom file chooser class ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us the declaration (and initialization) of the the variable `fc`. [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [do not add code as screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I reinstall netbeans and jdk and all works. Thank you all